# Can you spawn special villagers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft 1.3.1, the different types of villagers are now important as they trade different things. However, not all types will necessarily spawn at once. If I occupy a village that lacks, say, a blacksmith, can I encourage one to spawn, perhaps by  building a forge?

Comment: If you don't mind cheating, there is an [MCEdit filter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13LyPP43twE&feature=youtube_gdata_player) that you can use to spawn in specific villagers.

Comment: Or use Spawn Eggs in creative - they now spawn all types randomly. Just murder the ones you don't need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just build more houses [of the normal type](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villagers#Mating_and_population) until you get a blacksmith. The profession of a new child is random, and independent of its parents' professions.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:#,buy:{id:#,Count:#,Damage:#},buyB:{id:#,Count:#,Damage:#},sell:{id:#,Count:#,Damage:#}}]}}
```